# Manage DHCP on windows server from computer outside domain

Tags: windows, dhcp, active-directory

I am trying to manage a DHCP server running on Windows Server 2008r2 from a computer that is not in my active directory domain. I currently get the error: `This call was performed by a client who is not a member of the \"DHCP Administrators\" security group.` I know that the user attempting to access must be a member of the DHCP Administrators group, how can I tell my application to connect to the server as a domain account or allow Everyone to be DHCP administrators. Security is not a concern, I tried adding everyone and anonymous to the group in active directory, but neither group exists. I want to avoid adding my computer to the domain.

Comment: You would need to add the device to the domain.  You won't be able to access this information from a local user outside the domain for obvious reasons.  There is no way to add a user that only exists on a machine outside of the domain to a group that exists on the domain.

Comment: That stinks, I hate when permissions get in the way. If only I could use Linux :(

Answer (score 1):

You need to run the snap-in as a different user. You can change the shortcut target field to:

%SystemRoot%\system32\runas /savecred /user:yourdomain\domainuser "mmc dhcpmgmt.msc"

Reference: http://www.jimguckin.com/2013/08/how-to-elevate-rsat-shortcuts/